# Wrapping (filling) a long list of strings in Emacs (clojure-mode)

Tags: emacs, clojure, word-wrap

In Emacs (in Clojure mode), I want to fill this:

```
(def items
  ["freezing" "drum" "lean" "deputy" "deputy" "session" "critic" "ace" "rat" "racket" "trap" "inconvenient" "guidance" "ruins"])
```

So that it looks like this:

```
(def items
  ["freezing" "drum" "lean" "deputy" "deputy" "session" "critic" "ace"
   "rat" "racket" "trap" "inconvenient" "guidance" "ruins"])
```

I'm looking for a function to do it. I have tried, without success:

- `M-q` (e.g. `paredit-reindent-defun`)
- `C-u M-q` (e.g. `paredit-reindent-defun`)
- `M-x fill-paragraph`
- `C-u M-x fill-paragraph`

Answer (score 3):

`fill-region-as-paragraph` is what you want.

You can optionally pretty-print (to a string or a buffer) using a function from library `pp.el`, before filling.  Pretty-printing will not do the filling, but if you are showing a Lisp sexp it will make a big difference in the line width and readability.

Comment: Yes. To clarify: (1) create a selection around the vector (e.g. `[` to the `]`) (2) Press `M-x fill-region-as-paragraph`.

Comment: Yes, except you do not have to "*create a selection*" - just pass the start and end positions to the function.  And if such a vector is part of a larger sexp, pretty-printing the sexp first will also help with line-width and readability.

Comment: For interactive use, how do you pass the start and end positions?

Comment: If you mean using `fill-region-as-paragraph` itself interactively, then it operates on the active region. If you mean in your own command, then see the doc for function `interactive` - e.g., `"r"`, which, again, picks up the active region limits. If you mean something else, please specify. (You can also use `interactive` with a Lisp sexp instead of a string arg, to specify the args. That is what `fill-region-as-paragraph` does, for example.)

Answer (score 1):

[`lispy-fill`](https://github.com/abo-abo/lispy) can do this.

In the gif below, `fill-column` is at `70`, and:

- <kbd>M-q</kbd> fills
- <kbd>f</kbd> and <kbd>h</kbd> move cursor
- <kbd>O</kbd> un-fills

[image: lispy-fill]

Comment: Does lispy-fill work well with paredit? Do you recommend using them together?

Comment: How did you make the GIF animation in your answer?

Comment: `lispy` completely replaces `paredit` for me. But you can mix them up if you want.

Comment: For the gif, I used Kazam to take the pictures and this recipe to compile it:
https://github.com/abo-abo/make-it-so/blob/master/recipes/gif/gifsicle/Makefile